# Wordpress Limit Login Attempt plugin in custom login form

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication, limit

Has anyone tried to implement the WordPress plugin - "Limit Login Attempt" into a custom login page template?

In my custom template, I inserted:

```
<div class="msg-error"">
<p>
    <!--The credentials entered are incorrect. Please try again.-->
    <?php
        echo limit_login_get_message(); 
    ?>  
</p>
```

The error produced: 2999 attempts remaining. But, when you try to re-enter an invalid password or username again, the error stays the same and doesn't change.

If anyone has done so, can you please assist me?

Thanks.

------------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------

I tried this:

```
$user = wp_signon($credentials, false);

if (is_wp_error($user)) { // True, check for errors and display them

    echo '<div class="msg-error">' . $user->get_error_message() . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="msg-error">' . limit_login_get_message() . '</div>';  // Display Limit Login Login Attempt message
} else {
    wp_redirect(site_url());    // Redirect them to home page
}
```

When the user enters the incorrect credentials, WP generates its errors but not the limit login attempt errors but if I add
**echo limit_login_get_message();**, it displays the # of remaining attempts (static, the # doesn't change upon multiple incorrect credentials....)

Still pondering on this...

------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------
Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
if ($user_ID) {
// Send logged in user back to home page if they are trying to access this page
header('Location:' . home_url());
} else { // If user aren't logged in, Continue log in process
if (isset($_POST["submit-log"])) {  // Check for submit button

global $wpdb, $user; // WP Global variables

$username = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['username']);    // SQL escape & Fetch username input text
$password = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['password']);    // SQL escape & Fetch password input text
$remember = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['rememberme']);  // SQL escape & Fetch remember checkbox

if ($remember) // True, checkbox has been checked
    $remember = "true";
else    // False
    $remember = "false";

$credentials = array(); // Create an array to hold the user input data
$credentials['user_login'] = $username;
$credentials['user_password'] = $password;
$credentials['remember'] = $remember;

$user = wp_signon($credentials, false);

if (is_wp_error($user)) { // True, check for errors and display them

    echo '<div class="msg-error">' . $user->get_error_message() . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="msg-error">' . limit_login_get_message() . '</div>';  // Display Limit Login Login Attempt message
} else {
    wp_redirect(site_url());    // Redirect them to home page
}
} else {
// Do nothing
}
}
?>
<div id="login-container">
<h3>Membership Login</h3>
<div class="ws-plugin--s2member-pro-login-widget">
    <form id="login" name="form" action="<?php echo esc_html(home_url()); ?>/login/" method="post">
        <div class="login-username">
            <label for="login-username">Username:</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="login-pw">
            <label for="login-password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="lost-pw">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_html(site_url('/register')); ?>">signup now</a> | <a href="<?php echo esc_html(site_url('/resetpass')); ?>">forgot password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cust-remember-me">
            <label for "remember-me">Remember me</label><input id="remember-me" type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
        </div>
        <div class="cust-login-submit">
            <input id="cust-submit-log" type="hidden" name="hidden-submit-log">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit-log" value="Submit">
        </div>          
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<?php
global $error;
$referrer = $_GET['login'];
 if ($referrer == 'false'){
    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>';
    echo $error;
    echo '</p></div>';
 } else {
 }
?>
```

If you do not want to use the plugin, you can use the following by placing it in your `functions.php`.  This is from this [source](https://coderwall.com/p/dc2bbg).

```
<?php
/**
 * CLASS LIMIT LOGIN ATTEMPTS
 * Prevent Mass WordPress Login Attacks by setting locking the system when login fail.
 * To be added in functions.php or as an external file.
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Limit_Login_Attempts' ) ) {
    class Limit_Login_Attempts {

        var $failed_login_limit = 3;                    //Number of authentification accepted
        var $lockout_duration   = 1800;                 //Stop authentification process for 30 minutes: 60*30 = 1800
        var $transient_name     = 'attempted_login';    //Transient used

        public function __construct() {
            add_filter( 'authenticate', array( $this, 'check_attempted_login' ), 30, 3 );
            add_action( 'wp_login_failed', array( $this, 'login_failed' ), 10, 1 );
        }

        /**
         * Lock login attempts of failed login limit is reached
         */
        public function check_attempted_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
            if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
                $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );

                if ( $datas['tried'] >= $this->failed_login_limit ) {
                    $until = get_option( '_transient_timeout_' . $this->transient_name );
                    $time = $this->when( $until );

                    //Display error message to the user when limit is reached 
                    return new WP_Error( 'too_many_tried', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You have reached authentification limit, you will be able to try again in %1$s.' ) , $time ) );
                }
            }

            return $user;
        }


        /**
         * Add transient
         */
        public function login_failed( $username ) {
            if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
                $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );
                $datas['tried']++;

                if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit )
                    set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
            } else {
                $datas = array(
                    'tried'     => 1
                );
                set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
            }
        }


        /**
         * Return difference between 2 given dates
         * <a href="/param">@param</a>  int      $time   Date as Unix timestamp
         * @return string           Return string
         */
        private function when( $time ) {
            if ( ! $time )
                return;

            $right_now = time();

            $diff = abs( $right_now - $time );

            $second = 1;
            $minute = $second * 60;
            $hour = $minute * 60;
            $day = $hour * 24;

            if ( $diff < $minute )
                return floor( $diff / $second ) . ' secondes';

            if ( $diff < $minute * 2 )
                return "about 1 minute ago";

            if ( $diff < $hour )
                return floor( $diff / $minute ) . ' minutes';

            if ( $diff < $hour * 2 )
                return 'about 1 hour';

            return floor( $diff / $hour ) . ' hours';
        }
    }
}

//Enable it:
new Limit_Login_Attempts();
?>
```

Comment: I would prefer using the plugin just in case I get locked out, my host can unlock my IP for me but thanks, this seems to be a great solution for my other website.

Comment: @rolu I provided another solution

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. It was an issue in the plugin settings. All is working now.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I'd not have reported this if it was just LQ. The problem is it doesn't explain what the issue was, and so is unlikely to be of use to future readers - that's the critical metric. Hence NAA (IMO).

Comment: @halfer On reconsideration, I think you're right.  Thanks for following up.  I blame the recent "don't delete non-crap" post on Meta for putting me in a keep-first frame of mind.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey, and no probs! Yes, I think I saw that - there are definitely grey areas (rolu, if you can expand on this answer a bit, that would be most helpful - thanks. I appreciate it is quite old).